# Spotfire Table giving number can it show percentage using custom expression

Tags: percentage, spotfire

I hope you are well. I have a table in Spotfire. see Picture [image: SPotfire table]

I was wondering if using a custom expression if the 903, 34 and 1 could be turned into percentages, 96.6, 3.3 and .1 using a custom expression.

**EDIT TO ADD PICTURES OF ERROR**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvAVk.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYaXd.png

third pic [image]

Comment: Did the solution below work for you once you placed it on the correct axis?

Comment: Hi not really I applied it to the X Axis but the figures that come back are for complete 903 changes to complete 301 In Progress 34 turns to In Progress 11.33 and Open 1 turns to Open .033, Have i done something wrong? I will put up another screen shot it may be more clear. Again thank you so much for the assistance it is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Thanks Philip. I noticed you are wanting the percentages on a non-numeric column. My apologies. See my answer below underneath the EDIT

Comment: @scsimon.The last edit worked. Awesome Awesome stuff you the man. Much respect from Dublin Ireland. thank you for all the help. :-) have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the comparative percentage... is this correct? Try this out:

```
Count([Status]) THEN [Value] / Count([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.Rows])) as [% of Total]
```

This expression will give you what the percentage of your count is for the total. Your total is 938 so this will give you the result of 903/938, 34/938, and 1/938. Next you need to do this:

> Right Click > Properties > Formatting > Change the [% of Total] Axis to the Percentage Category

This will format your value as a percentage from a decimal.

**EDIT**

I noticed you were aggregating off of a non integer field. Use this expression instead:

```
Count() THEN [Value] / Sum([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.Rows]))
```

Also, depending on your data (if there is more than one row per site id) you will want to use a unique count instead:

```
UniqueCount() THEN [Value] / Sum([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.Rows]))
```

Comment: Hi scsimon. Thank you for your support it is very much appreciated. I have entered what you gave me and wrapped it in <> but I am now getting a pop up 'The expression is not valid after 'THEN' on line 1 character 18' any help would be greatly welcomed

Comment: Where are you entering it

Comment: I added some more pics of what I am attempting to do. hopefully you can help with the issue. Again thank you so much for the help it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipConnell I moved them to your original post--you'll see them there soon. I'll take a look at your error.

Comment: @PhilipConnell you want to add this expression to the VALUE AXIS of your chart. This would be the same place you have Count(Status) and Avg(#days open)

Comment: @scsimon.The last edit worked. Awesome Awesome stuff you the man. Much respect from Dublin Ireland. thank you for all the help. :-) have a great day

Comment: @PhilipConnell I lived in Europe for 2 years and Ireland was the one place i missed out on! Huge fan of your brew, especially the jameson that we can't get over here like the special reserve! Cheers!

Comment: Duboin is 'banging' right now mate silicon valley of Europe. Sorry to hear you cant get Jameson but when you are next in an airport check out Jameson Caskmates edition. Jameson took the Stout aka Guinness barrels from Guinness and put whisky in them, left them for a few year and now are selling. get some you will not be disappointed :-)

Comment: @PhilipConnell that sounds freaking awesome! Thanks for the advice!